# Como receber dados de um formulario html com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Boa tarde, sou novato nesta área e estou tendo problemas para receber os dados de meu formulário html com meu código PHP. Meu problema é que estou usando para o **name** das **Inputs** o seguinte formato **name="data[Curriculo][name]"**, 
 porém quando insiro o **name da Input** em meu código Php ele não recebe os dados.
Segue o código que estou usando é outros que já tentei como possíveis soluções:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="formAddCurriculo" class="form-default" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="conexão.php" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" /></div>

<h5 class="title-field whit-padding">Dados Pessoais</h5>

<fieldset class="clearfix mbottom sides-margin">
    <div class="input text">
        <label for="CurriculoName" class="required">Nome Completo</label>
          <input name="data[Curriculo][name]" type="text" class="field field-big" maxlength="255" id="CurriculoName" /></div>

    <div class="input text">
        <label for="CurriculoRg">RG</label>
            <input name="data[Curriculo][rg]" type="text" class="field field-medium" maxlength="14" id="CurriculoRg" /></div>

    <div class="input text required">
        <label for="CurriculoCpf" class="required">CPF</label>
        <input name="data[Curriculo][cpf]" type="text" class="field field-medium cpf" maxlength="50" id="CurriculoCpf" /></div>

    <fieldset class="clearfix sides-margin">
    <div class="submit"><input class="to-upper fright btn-green ts" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" /></div> 

        </fieldset>

                            </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "**********";
$username = "***********";
$password = "************";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";


// RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !


$data[Curriculo][name] = $_POST ['$data[Curriculo][name]']; 
$data[Curriculo][rg] = $_POST ['data[Curriculo][rg]']; 
$data[Curriculo][cpf]f = $_POST ['data[Curriculo][cpf]']; 


$Usuarios = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (ID,NomeCompleto, RG, CPF)VALUES((Null,'$data[Curriculo][name]','data[Curriculo][rg]','data[Curriculo][cpf]')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $Usuarios)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $Usuarios . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**Porém não recebe os dados das Inputs, Sei que pode parecer algo óbvio mas não consegui encontrar a solução na documentação do PHP, e não gostaria de mudar o nome das Inputs pois tenho os códigos de validação javascript e a folha de estilo escritas neste formato**

Comment: O php exibe algum erro ou apenas os dados no banco ficam em branco?? Percebi que faltam as aspas e o ponto e virgula no final do seu codigo sql.

Comment: Depois de receber os dados no php tente um `var_dump($_POST);` e poste aqui pra gente conferir se você ta recebendo os dados ou não.

Comment: Debug simples. No inicio do arquivo php, logo após a tag de abertura coloque o var_dump citado pelo @JoãoVictorSouza

Comment: Juliano, se você colocar assim no HTML: `<input name="data['Curriculo']['rg']" type="text"`, com aspas simples? No PHP, pegaria assim: `$data["Curriculo"]["name"] = $_POST['$data[Curriculo][name]'];`

Comment: Por que não simplificar e `<input name="curriculo_rg" type="text"` ? No PHP `$_POST['curriculo_rg'];`

Comment: Após eu acrescentar o var_dump($_POST);, exibe a mensagem que esta recebendo os dados :**Connected successfullyarray(2) { ["_method"]=> string(4) "POST" ["data"]=> array(2) { ["Curriculo"]=> array(62) { ["name"]=> string(18) "juliano corolesqui" ["rg"]=> string(8) "58558507" ["cpf"]=> string(14) "082.384.288-81"} } } New record created successfully**  Porén no banco da dados grava os seguintes dados nos campos **Array[name]
Array[rg]
Array[cpf]
0000-00-00**

Comment: tente $_POST['data']['Curriculo']['name']

Comment: seu código está com diversos erros de sintaxe.

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando o nome dos inputs como se fossem matrizes. Você realmente precisa disso? Você irá alterar os dados de mais de um usuário? Se não precisar, procure simplificar o nome dos inputs. Você poderia deixar o nome deles da seguinte forma:

```
<input name="name" type="text" class="field field-big" maxlength="255" id="CurriculoName" />

<input name="rg" type="text" class="field field-medium" maxlength="14" id="CurriculoRg" />

<input name="cpf" type="text" class="field field-medium cpf" maxlength="50" id="CurriculoCpf" />
```

Considerando que você simplificou o nome nos inputs, você poderia pegar o valor dos input no PHP dessa forma:

```
$data["Curriculo"]["name"] = $_POST["name"]; 
$data["Curriculo"]["rg"] = $_POST["rg"]; 
$data["Curriculo"]["cpf"] = $_POST["cpf"];
```

Mas novamente você estará usando matriz. Se não for necessário. Você também pode simplicar as variáveis.

```
$name = $_POST["name"]; 
$rg = $_POST["rg"]; 
$cpf = $_POST["cpf"];
```

Comment: Menos é mais, simplifique seu código